# KendoUI Mobile: Input type date, wrong format/culture

Tags: html, date, input, kendo-mobile, icenium

I have a problem with a date-input in my KendoUI Mobile application.
The input displays the value in the default format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) but I want the input to display the value in a differnet format like `dd.MM.yyyy`.

Is there a possibility to change the format?

The online demo also shows my default culture date format so I think it is not impossible.
http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/forms/index.html

Update: The content is shown inside a Icenium generated APP and not in a default browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: The Code is written and displayed in Icenium/Telerik APP Builder. So it is not related to a default browser view. I added the Icenium Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it using `kendo.toString(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy")`.

find more info [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting)